# graphql query with fetch producing 400 bad request

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I am trying to write a basic graphql query with fetch that works when using apollo client. But it does not work with node-fetch.

The type definitions look like this:

```
type Query {
  findLeadStat(print: PrintInput!): LeadStatWithPrint
}

input PrintInput {
  printa: String!
  service: String
}

type LeadStatWithPrint {
  answered: Int!
  printa: String!
  service: String
}
```

This is the node-fetch query:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

( async () => {    
    const uri = `http://localhost:3000/graphql/v1`;

    const query = `
        query findLeadStat(print: PrintInput!) {
          findLeadStat(print: $print){
            answered
            printa
            service
          }
        } 
    `;

    // I also tried add a query: key inside data object
    const data = {
            print: {
                printa: "62f69234a7901e3659bf67ea2f1a758d",
                service: "abc"
              }
    }

    const response = await fetch(uri, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({query, data})
    });

    console.log('and the resp: ', response);
})()
```

It gives me:

```
url: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql/v1',
status: 400,
statusText: 'Bad Request',
```

It works in Apollo GraphQL Client. Why doesn't it work with fetch?

So when I was using async await with node-fetch, the response was pretty much useless. It was just telling me there was a 400 bad request error and then give me this long object of properties, none of them containing the actual error message.

But when I changed the fetch call to this:

```
const response = await fetch(uri, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query, variables}) // same as query: query, variables: variables
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => console.log(json))
.catch(err => console.error('ERROR: ', err));
```

There two lines right here:

```
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => console.log(json))
```

made it clear what the issue was:

```
{
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'Syntax Error: Expected $, found Name "fingeprint"',
      locations: [Array],
      extensions: [Object]
    }
  ]
}
```

It appears node-fetch has two async events occurring and so await had to be used twice:

```
const response = await fetch(uri, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query, variables}) // same as query: query, variables: variables
})

console.log('and the resp: ', await response.json());
```

Answer (score 2):

A 400 status indicates your query was invalid or malformed. When this happens, the response will include a JSON body with an `errors` array that can be inspected to determine what exactly went wrong.

In this particular case, the issue is that your query includes a non-nullable variable (`$print`) but this variable was not provided along with the query.

When making a GraphQL request, the request body should be a JSON object with a `query` property and two other optional properties -- `variables` and `operationName`. `operationName` is used to identify which operation to execute if multiple operations were included in the provided document (the `query` property). Any non-nullable variables defined in the executed operation must be included as properties under the `variables` property, which is also an object. Nullable properties may be omitted altogether.

In other words, you need to change the `data` property in your request to `variables` in order for the server to recognize that the variable was provided with the request.